# Socket IO Live call and Video call (MEAN)

Tags: angular, websocket, socket.io, mean, meanjs

I am working on my  Live chat Application (MEAN) . I have successfully completed a chat application ,I am using socket IO in node js. now I want to add a calling feature and also a video calling. what is the best way to achieve it ? should i  socket-io p2p ? suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use WebRTC to provide the video and audio over the web.  Using WebRTC you can provide a direct p2p connection.

This looks to be a good example you can checkout.
**https://github.com/taylorhayduk/ExpertRTC**

Comment: i am trying to achieve it from sockt.io.  (typescriipt)  i am able to send  image and video sharing. now i have got the data from webcam on client side trying to stream with socket io, if it works good,if not i will start integrating  webrtc,  the example you referenced me is very old.

Comment: I would like to know your conclusions of implement it with socket.io